# Clear Dash Searchbox after search and Start a Program

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-dash

if top left enters a search term in the search box DASH, eg "fir" is then for example Firefox displayed. All well and good, how can you adjust the one that deletes the Dash search the word "fir" to start the program.

So next time look for the input box is "empty".

I am aware that the box empties automatically when you re-enter a word. But that's what I do not want the field SHOULD be empty.

Can this be set somewhere so that open the input field is empty after the next?

Thank you

Sorry for my bad English, I'm a german User

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or <kbd>Delete</kbd> (<kbd>Del</kbd>), or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (<kbd>←</kbd>) when you open Dash again. <kbd>Esc</kbd> key will empty the content of the input field in any circumstances, even if the text is not selected. It doesn't take more than a second.